# Kendo Grid filtering using 2 decimal places when DataSource data uses 4 decimals

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo Grid displaying dollar amounts but the data in the DataSource returns 4 decimal places.

The DataSource data looks something like this:

```
{ totalDollars: 1513.1548 },
{ totalDollars: 158.2903 },
{ ... }
```

So to display the number correctly I use the column format...

```
columns: [
    { field: 'totalDollars', format: '{0:c2}' },
    { ... }
]
```

But now I want to filter this column. If I filter with `"Is Equal To"` `159.29` it fails.

I've made it work using 4 decimals and using `column.filterable.ui`:

```
columns: [
    {
        field: 'totalDollars',
        format: '{0:c2}',
        filterable: {
            ui: function(e) {
                element.kendoNumericTextBox({
                    format: "n4",
                    decimals: 4
                });
            }
        }
    }
]
```

But this doesn't help because the user doesn't know the last 2 decimals. So I need it to only use up to 2 decimals when filtering.

Is this possible?

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/53pqe3mo/) - note that filtering by "Mono Cost" using `7133.03` doesn't work but `7133.0332` does. I'm looking to make `7133.03` work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/53pqe3mo/2/

But essentially you can override the default parser for the value being returned by adding the following:

```
DefaultMonoCPP: {
                    editable: false,
                    type: "number",  
                    parse: function(e)
                    {
                        console.log(e);
                         return  kendo.parseFloat(kendo.toString(e,"c2"));  
                    }
```

I have added the console.log line just to show you that the value actually being passed in is the original supplied by the datasource.

It took a little finding but this link should help:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/model#methods-Model.define

edit:

updated answer based on comments.

for future reference use this link:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/numberparsing

Comment: Ahhh. I just came across a bug here. Go to your jsfiddle and try to filter "Mono Cost" and do "less than 1000". Seems like a kendo bug but I'm not sure.

Comment: It's the same in the latest Kendo as well. http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/bky2v1at/

Comment: have just done an update. http://jsfiddle.net/bky2v1at/2/ if this works I will update the answer to reflect this change for you.

Comment: Slick! How'd you know that?!?!? Thank you!

Comment: added link to number parsing and updated answer. Glad it helped.

Comment: You've been ridiculously helpful and I don't want to keep bothering you. But you're good! :) If you're willing to, I have another related question posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631294/format-kendo-grid-column-filter-for-percentages (sorry if this is breaking any SO rules)