# Format Kendo grid column filter for percentages

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I have a kendo grid and my datasource data returns number with unknown decimal places. So I'm using a parse function on the datasource to compensate for that.

```
DefaultMonoCPP: {
    editable: false,
    type: "number",  
    parse: function(e) {
        return  kendo.parseFloat(kendo.toString(e,"p4")); 
    }
}
```

Now when I filter, I don't want it to automatically multiply the percentage by 100. So I have `filterable` set on the columns.

```
    {
        field: "DefaultMonoCPP",
        title: "Mono Cost",
        format: '{0:p4}',
        filterable: {
            ui: function(e) {
                e.kendoNumericTextBox({
                    //format: "{0:p4}",
                    //format: "p4",
                    format: "##.0000 \\%",
                    decimals: 4
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

But this messes up the filtered number (1.2700% => 1.27). So filtering fails.

JSFiddle for clarification: http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/mecny50f/

Is there any way to have both the parse and filterable work correctly together?

Comment: can you clarify something for me. Will there ever be an occasion when something will be more than 100%? So I expect you are looking for something like the user entering 25.0231 would be 0.250231 when used for filtering. e.g. is the range 0% - 100% or can it be anything form 0% to 100+%

Comment: Good question. It looks like it'll never be over 100%. And correct - if a user enters 25.0231, I'd like it to filter the datasource for 0.250231 but display to the user as 25.0231%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to format the numeric textbox as a percentage and set the step to 0.01 so that it increments/decrements 1% at a time. If you're worried about the user typing in a percentage as a whole number, handle it in the change event.

```
e.kendoNumericTextBox({
    format: '{0:p4}',
    step: 0.01,
    decimals: 4,
    change: function () {
        var val = this.value();
        if (val > 1) {
            this.value(val / 100);
            this.trigger("change");
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m741o9tL/3/)

Comment: Right. But if I enter a number manually it still multiplies by 100. So 12.7 -> 127.0000%. I'd love for it to stay at 1.2700%.

Comment: Did you try this out? It isn't working for me... even when removing the "on change, trigger change" infinite loop :) I think you're on to something though. I'll have to play around with it.

Comment: It works, but it triggers an infinite loop and throws a call stack error http://i.imgur.com/rLgHY6H.png There's gotta be a workaround. I haven't played with it yet.

Comment: FYI - with your solution, I wasn't able to enter numbers less than 1 (so typing 0.16 wouldn't work). I've made a modification here to allow for all numbers. http://jsfiddle.net/dmathisen/zjvsqyjh/

Comment: @dmathisen That's a good solution but you should set the `step` value back to `1` in that case.